# no option for postgis shapefile import/export manager in pg admin III

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, postgis, pgadmin

I do not have the PostGIS shapefile Import/Export Manager tool in the PgAdmin III.Postgres version 9.4.4-3, postgis version2.1.8 . I am using ubuntu 14.04. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

This procedure is only tested on Ubuntu:

1. Open this file with a text editor (as sudo user): `/usr/share/pgadmin3/plugins.d/plugins.ini`
2. At end of the file add this code:

   ```
   ;PostGIS shp2pgsql-gui:
   ;;
   Title=PostGIS Shapefile and DBF loader
   Command=$$PGBINDIR/shp2pgsql-gui -h "$$HOSTNAME" -p $$PORT -U "$$USERNAME" -d "$$DATABASE" -W "$$PASSWORD"
   Description=Open a PostGIS ESRI Shapefile or Plain dbf loader console to the current database.
   KeyFile=$$PGBINDIR/shp2pgsql-gui
   Platform=unix
   ServerType=postgresql
   Database=Yes
   SetPassword=Yes
   ```
3. Save and close the file, restart pgadmin

Credits: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/145-PgAdmin-III-Plug-in-Registration-PostGIS-Shapefile-and-DBF-Loader.html

Comment: It still does not work! PG Bin path in options shows /user/bin , is that fine?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did that got it working on Ubuntu 16.04:

1. First install postgis and it's gui

   `sudo apt-get install postgis postgis-gui`

   Some older tutorials instruct you to install `opengeo-postgis2-shapeloader`, but it seems that this package is depreciated. ̀̀`postgis-gui` contains `shp2pgsql-gui`.
2. Now edit `/usr/share/pgadmin3/plugins.d/plugins.ini` as explained by Tommaso,    by adding the following lines:

   ```
   ;  
   ;PostGIS shp2pgsql-gui: 
   ;  
   Title=PostGIS Shapefile and DBF loader
   Command=$$PGBINDIR/shp2pgsql-gui -h "$$HOSTNAME" -p $$PORT -U "$$USERNAME" -d "$$DATABASE" -W "$$PASSWORD"
   Description=Open a PostGIS ESRI Shapefile or Plain dbf loader console to the current database.
   KeyFile=$$PGBINDIR/shp2pgsql-gui
   Platform=unix
   ServerType=postgresql
   Database=Yes
   SetPassword=Yes
   ```
3. At this point, the item appeared in my plugin menu, but it was still greyed-out. What I did was run the `postgis-gui`, click on "view connection details...", and set up a connection to my Postgres database and imported a shapefile to test
4. Restarted pgAdmin III et Voilà!